# What are the strengths and weaknesses of Rido saddles?

Tags: product-rec, saddle, ergonomics

I've started riding more often now (big plus), and as a result am getting, ahem, saddle issues with my classic [San Marco Rolls saddle](http://www.wiggle.co.uk/selle-san-marco-rolls-saddle-with-steel-rails/). I'm an average build, 5' 8-9". The saddle issues are mainly chafing at the top of my legs, some more serious skin damage, and general soreness.

I've heard good things about [Rido saddles](http://www.rido-cyclesaddles.com/new-rido-r-lt-pre-launch-info-c100130.html). Specifically that they transfer the weight from the perineum to the assbones which are better built for weight distribution.

What are these saddles best and worst at? Are they good for particular types of riding, or riders with particular builds? Are they good for particular kinds of bikes? I ride a [Batavus Pro Team road bike](https://www.lfgss.com/thread79524.html) circa 1990 which is about right size for me.

Is there anything specific to this saddle that has to be taken into account, position of saddle fore and aft, angle of saddle, or position of handle-bar stem, etc?

Comment: I've edited this so it's less of a let-talk-about-saddles question and a more answerable, stack-exchange-style question. I had to make a few guesses, so please revert my edits if I've missed the point. Also, indications of what kind of issues you're currently getting would be helpful. Chafing on your legs? Numbness? General soreness?

Comment: "Chafing at the top of my legs" would suggest that you're not wearing bike shorts, the simplest "fix" I know of for that problem.

Comment: Nope, bike shorts are on. It's not particularly bad, but is there. My legs were used to it before, but its been years since I've biked hard, so I am hoping my legs will get a bit "harder".

Comment: I generally find a saddle with the depression along the centerline to be more comfortable.  I don't see anything particularly unique about the Rido, though.  (Best saddle I ever used was a Velo similar to their Bio:Logic but with a glove leather cover.  Have not been able to find it anywhere, though.)

Comment: Yes I understand about the depression along the centreline. I think this is a similar approach the Rido saddles take - put the pressure somewhere else other than the...important bits.

When I watched the person riding his bike with the Rido saddle, his weight did seem to be over his assbones and so saw the benefit of it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think a Rido is worth trying in your situation. Of course, make sure your bike fits you properly, saddle height and tilt are properly adjusted, and so on.

I found my Rido saddle to be good for riding with padded shorts, but not so comfortable with street clothes. The saddles seem to be designed for moderate distance riding in a sporty position.

[image]

Of course, the only way to tell if this saddle will work for you will be to try it, but I think that a saddle like the one I had (see the picture) may work for you. When I rode the pictured bike for rides of half an hour to 45 minutes, the Rido took care of my chafing issues (the same as the ones you're having), since the saddle's nose is fairly narrow. When I replaced that bike with a Bike Friday and a Brooks, I replaced the Rido with the original saddle and turned this bike into a city pootling bike.

Comment: It's worth noting that this saddle is fairly old. Answers from anyone who knows about more recent Rido models would be welcome.